# Regex to capture <img> tags fails when "src" value is different

Tags: regex, perl

I use a regex to extract `<img src="img.jpg">` tags

Here is my regex

```
my @accept = $message_body =~ /<img src=\"\S*\">/gi;
```

Now my regex fails when the img tag is like this: `<img src="cid:img.jpg">`

Can any one tell me why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Your regex does not fail because of the additional "cid:".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

The greedyness of `\"\S*\"` says that it'll match as many non space characters as possible before the last `"` appears in the string. You could change this to `\".*?\"` which will match any characters upto the next `"`.

I would completely overhaul your expression so that it would avoid some other difficult HTML edge cases.

This expression will:

- match img tags which have an src attribute
- capture the src attribute value
- avoid messy html edge cases like:

  - like `>` or something that looks like an attribute inside an embedded javascript function
  - attributes which end with `src` like `hrefsrc="somevalue"`
- Although not used for this problem because you're only looking for a single attribute, the `(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=['"]([^"]*)['"])` construct allows multiple attributes to appear in any order inside the img tag.

`<img\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=['"]([^"]*)['"])(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?>`

[image]

## Example

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/bRmdy0YA0S

**Sample Text**

Note how the second image tag has some of the really difficult edge cases.

```
<img src="cid:img.jpg">
<img hrefsrc="NotMe.jpg" onmouseover=' src="NotTheMeEither.jpg" ; if ( 6 > x ) { funRotator(src) ; } ; ' src="cid:DifficultToFind.jpg">
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <img src="cid:img.jpg">
[0][1] = cid:img.jpg

[1][0] = <img hrefsrc="NotMe.jpg" onmouseover=' src="NotTheMeEither.jpg" ; if ( 6 > x ) { funRotator(src) ; } ; ' src="cid:DifficultToFind.jpg">
[1][1] = cid:DifficultToFind.jpg
```

Comment: Wow, Denomales! http://gifrific.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Waynes-World-Were-not-Worthy.gif

Answer (score 3):

The `*` quantifier is greedy: it matches as much as it can while allowing the rest of the pattern to match. In your case, `\S*` is likely consuming more text than you intended.

Consider using

```
my @accept = $message_body =~ /<img src="\S*?">/gi;
```

or

```
my @accept = $message_body =~ /<img src="[^"]+">/gi;
```

These patterns attempt to stop matching as soon as they detect a closing double-quote, but they are heuristics that could fail depending on how friendly your input is. To do the job properly, use an HTML parser.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think double quotes in the regex needs escaping.

Comment: @doubleDown you were right; regex doesn't need escaping, I meant by fail that this token <img src="cid:img.jpg"> should appear but it doesn't when I used my regex or yours, sorry for misleading

Comment: @A'amerMohamed Are other img tags appearing? Note that the patterns above require exactly one space (not tab) between `img` and `src`. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case you missed n0rd's comment, here is the [essential link again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/111036) about the use of regular expressions with (X|HT)ML.

With that out of the way, here is one way to do it with a module (of course, just as [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIMTOWTDI), there is also more than one module that would be suitable)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie qw(open);

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $file = shift or die "Missing argument! Usage: $0 FILENAME\n";

open( F, $file );

my $t=HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new();

$t->parse_file($file)
    or die "Could not parse $file\n";

foreach my $img ( $t->findnodes( '//img' ) ) {

    my $src    = $img->attr('src');
    my $width  = $img->attr('width');
    my $height = $img->attr('height');

    print $img->as_HTML, "\n";
    foreach my $attr ( qw(src width height alt title) ) {
        print "$attr = ", $img->attr($attr), "\n" if defined($img->attr($attr));
    }
    print "\n";
}
```